# Iterate through Oracle SQL query results line by line, and produce sub-queries - not running efficiently

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, runtime

If have the below query (simplified example of my query, for the purposes of readability):

```
SELECT make, year, color, count(*) 
FROM cars
GROUPY BY make, year, color
ORDER BY 4 DESC;
```

I want to iterate through the resulting table and produce sub queries for the criteria of each row (examples below). I hope to then use these sub queries to make a single table with samples results (maybe 3 rows) that meet the criteria of each of the rows from the original query results (ex. as there are multiple Jeeps from 2019 in color black).

```
SELECT * from cars 
WHERE make = 'Jeep'
AND  year = '2019'
AND color = 'Black';


SELECT * from cars 
WHERE make = 'Ford'
AND year = '2018'
AND color = 'Red';
```

This may seem like an odd or unnecessary request. However, I believe that this is the best approach given the complexity of my actual problem. This is the approach I want to take, as I want a simplified solution that I can come back to and alter for future use and for different variations of queries.

I am currently using ROW_NUMBER() to retrieve a maximum of three rows per group as my approach (below). Although this compiles for me, it has never run to completion because it has a very long runtime. When I go through the process manually (that I hope to automate with this query), the runtime to produce the desired output doesn't take too long (an hour or two). However, when I run this solution it remains running for the entire day and then Oracle stops the process as a result of the database connection timing out. Does anyone have a better approach to this problem, or perhaps a way to make this run more efficiently?

```
select *
from (
  select c.*,
    row_number() over(partition by make, year, color order by id) as rn
  from cars c
) x
where rn <= 3
```

NOTE: I am using Oracle SQL Developer

Comment: do you want only select statements ? or you will use these queries inside a proc or function ?

Comment: I am open to any approach, thanks.

Comment: i replied now, since i dont have some place to test, you can check if its work for you

Comment: Thanks for your idea, I hope to limit the amount of sample rows per group to 3 and I don't see that in your approach. Also your approach would be pulling from the entire cars table as opposed to the query results from my original query (the first one on this page)

Comment: its can be added easily. i just edited my answer. you can check

Comment: i am off to office. i hope it helps, next time adding a sql fiddle helps alot for you to get %100 working answers. good night

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c66a5448a4d994278097707c18726261

Comment: I attached a fiddle above! I am actually getting an error with the color reference in the string select statement. Let me know what you think.

Comment: i tested my answer. it seems working. let me know when you check https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a2eb35611ce32db094118d7d027aeba9

Answer (score 0):

You can get all queries by dynamically create  another column like :

```
    SELECT DISTINCT make, year, color, 
'SELECT * from cars WHERE make =''' || make ||''' AND  year = ''' || year ||''' AND color = ''' || color ||'''' AS SELECT_STATEMENTS
FROM (select *
from (
  select c.*,
    row_number() over(partition by make, year, color order by id) as rn
  from cars c
) x
where rn <= 3)
```

Comment: You'll want to add more quotes around the columns, like `make = ''' || make || '''`